# How To Create Child Window in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am converting my windows phone app to windows 8. i am unable to found child windows control in windows 8. can any one help on this.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Store Apps has Popup control. You can host any controls within it.

[Popup class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup)

[XAML Popup sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-Popup-sample-5ae00a42)

[Making a Popup Window in C# Windows Metro (WinRT)](http://winrtprogramming.wordpress.com/2012/10/16/making-a-popup-window-in-c-windows-metro-winrt/)